# Tengo un ciclo infinito

Tags: python, funciones

Estoy intentando hacer una función que determine si un número narcisista, es decir, un número que es igual a la suma de sus dígitos elevados a la cantidad de dígitos.
Se me ocurrio hacer esto:

```
potencia = 0
def es_narcisista(i):
  global potencia
  while i >0:
    división = i % 10
    potencia += 1
  while i >0:
    residuo = i %10
    suma += residuo **potencia
  if suma == i:
    return True
  else:
    return False
print(es_narcisista(153))
```

Este codigo se queda atorado en el primer while, sin importar el número que le pase a la función.
Tiene el `global potencia` para evitar el error de `local variable referenced before assignment`
Gracias.

Comment: while i > 0.. mientras i sea mayor que cero.. lo cual ocurre todo el tiempo, porque i siempre tiene el mismo valor....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución corta:

```
def es_narcisista(numero):
    snum = str(numero)
    potencia = len(snum)
    return sum(int(x) ** potencia for x in snum) == numero
```

Un número es narcisista si la suma de cada dígito elevado al número de digitos es igual al mismo numero.

**Demo**

```
print(es_narcisista(153))
print(es_narcisista(370))
print(es_narcisista(371))
print(es_narcisista(407))
print(es_narcisista(361))
```

produce

```
True
True
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Como se te dijo en los comentarios, tu ciclo `while` es infinito pues `i` siempre es mayor que `0` y nunca cambias su valor, una solucion seria ir cambiando el valor de `i` en cada iteración, pero no hare eso te mostrare una forma mas simplificada de hacerlo.

Como necesitamos elevar cada digito a la longitud del numero, tranformaremos el digito a un lista pero para eso habrá que convertirlo a string,

```py
potencia = 0
def es_narcisista(i):
  global potencia
  digits = list(str(i)) #tranformamos en lista, queda ['1','5','3']
  num_digit = len(digits) #obtenemos la longitud de lalista
  #sacamos la potencia iterando en cada digito y elevadolo a la longitud
  potencia = sum(int(dig)**num_digit for dig in digits )
  if i == potencia: #verificamos si es igual
      return True #retornamos True
  return False #retornamos False
```

**probamos**

```py
print(es_narcisista(153))
print(es_narcisista(370))
print(es_narcisista(371))
print(es_narcisista(361))
```

**resultado**

```
True
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por sus respuestas.
Le mostré el problema a uno de mis profesores, y él me explicó una forma de solucionarlo, y me quedó bastante claro la verdad.

```
def es_narcisista(i):
    b = str (i)
    sol = 0
    n = len(b)
    for j in range(n):
        sol = sol+ int (b[j])**n
    if sol == i:
        return True
    else:
        return False
n = int(input())
print(es_narcisista(n))
```

Cuando el input entra b, se cambia de formato `int` a `str` por lo que python divide los digitos automaticamente y a partir de este momento se puede tratar como una lista.
La n, representa la cantidad de dígitos, pues es la longitud de la lista b.
Luego, en el ciclo `for`, se toman, se elevan a la cantidad de digitos, y se suman los mismos.

Comment: es lo mismo que se te explicó en ambas respuestas, solo que esta solución es más larga. Una regla de Python es *escribe menos código siempre que sea posible*